# Regex to figure out a complex string

Tags: regex, parsing

I am trying to parse some text files into a database and there is a string that includes 2 pieces of information in it.
There are a few options for what the string can look like.
It can either look like a single word `Word` or it can have that first word, followed by a dash, followed by any number of other words like `Word - Second`.
The key though, is that IF the string ends in a number like `Word - Second 4` or two numbers separated by a slash like `Word - Second 2/3` then those numbers need to be put into a different variable.

I do NOT know enough about regex to do this one.  Help? (with explanations?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+(?: *- *[a-zA-Z]+(?: +[a-zA-Z]+)*)?)(?: +(\d+(?:\/\d+)?))?$
```

Explanation:

```
^               Start of line
(               First capturing group (for the words)
  [a-zA-Z]+     A word
  (?:...)?      (Omitted for clarity)
)               Close first group
(?:             Start non-capturing group
  \s+           Some whitespace
  (             Second capturing group (for the numbers)
    \d+         A number
    (?:\/\d+)?  Optionally a slash followed by another number
  )             Close capturing group
)?              Close optional non-capturing group
$               End of line
```

I omitted an explanation of this part above: `(?: *- *[a-zA-Z]+(?: +[a-zA-Z]+)*)?`. It matches a dash followed by one or more space separated words. I also wrote `\s` in the explanation instead of  because the space is invisible. But `\s` matches any whitespace, including new lines. You may prefer to match only spaces.

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/9839eZezBV)

Comment: You should escape your forward slashes.

Comment: Umm...yeah...that makes no sense at all to me.  Here's hoping it works!

Comment: Had to escape the forward slash as Stefan said, which made me realize I didn't provide enough information.  I don't need to find the strings that fit those criteria, I need to find the numbers inside those strings and pull them out.

Comment: @Pselus: Click the rubular link I provided and look on the right hand side of the page: all the words and numbers are "pulled out". Did you notice that? Is that what you want?

Comment: @Mark Byers: I think that is what I want.  But when I use it with the gsub function in Ruby, I just get the strings that fit the criteria and nothing else.  I think the problem now is that I don't know enough Ruby. :)
Thanks!

Comment: There is another problem with it as well.  The word after the dash can be any number of words.  So it could look like `Word - Second Third Seventh 3/3`.  This Regex is only grabbing lines that have a single word after the dash.

Comment: Yes, only one dash, but any number of words separated by a space each after the dash.